# VBA: Creating a Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel

I've been able to create Pivot Tables in code before but that was adding to a new worksheet.  I'm now trying to add a Pivot Table to an existing worksheet and am getting error message "Run-time error 1004: The PivotTable field name is not valid".  The code is below, my error begins in the last segment beginning with ActiveWorkbook and ending with xlPivotTableVersion14.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Public Sub AlliedPT()

Dim AlliedData As String
Dim SAProw As Long
Dim PivotSheet As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
SAProw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="AlliedData", RefersTo:= _
    "=Sheet1!$A$1:$N$" & SAProw

Sheets("PivotSheet").Select
PivotSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
  "AlliedData", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
  TableDestination:=PivotSheet & "!R3C6", TableName:="PivotTable18", 
  DefaultVersion _
  :=xlPivotTableVersion14

End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated, but *why* are you putting a line break/continuation between the `DefaultVersion` parameter name and the `:=xlPivotTableVersion14` value you're giving it?

Comment: I followed the Macro Recorder for that step of the process.  That should probably removed

Comment: Same for `SourceData:=` and `"AlliedData"` - the recorder is great for generating shitty code, you should always reformat it so that it's at least minimally decently readable ;-) ...and replace all the `.Select` with object references and member calls.

Comment: I think you should check your Row 1 Columns A-N in SHeet 1 and make sure there is a unique, non-blank column name for each column in your source data. The first row contains the pivot table field names.

Comment: Haha yes the Macro recorder can throw you off sometimes.  And thanks Kaciree you're a genius, that was the exact problem.  One column didn't have a title

Comment: @KacireeSoftware you should make that an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check your Row 1 Columns A-N in SHeet 1 and make sure there is a unique, non-blank column name for each column in your source data. The first row contains the pivot table field names.